# How do you call one Model from another Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models, Room and Layout.

```
Layout has_many :rooms
Room belongs_to :layout
```

Room has things like a smoking boolean. Layout has an occupancy_count.

In the Room class, I want a method that will return a list of rooms based on the smoking and occupancy_count variables. For example, I want to search for smoking rooms that can hold at least 4 people, or non smoking rooms that hold exactly 2, etc.

However, I can't for the life of me figure it out.

In the Room model I've tried...

```
def self.rooms_with_occupancy_and_smoking(occupancy_count, smoking)
    layouts = Layout.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count) //method self explanatory
    Room.rooms_with_smoking(smoking).joins(layouts) //method self explanatory
end
```

However, I get a

```
Runtime Error: Unknown Class : Layout (specifically when running the second line in that method)
```

How can I do something like this properly?

========= MODELS ============

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rooms

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :occupancy_count, presence: true

    def self.layouts_with_occupancy_count(occupancy_count)
        self.where('occupancy_count = ?', occupancy_count)
    end

    def self.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count)
        self.where('occupancy_count >= ?', occupancy_count)
    end

    def self.rooms_with_layout(layout_id)
        self.where(id: layout_id).rooms
    end
end


class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :layout
  has_many :visits

  validates :number, presence: true
  validates :rate, presence: true
  #validates :smoking, presence: true

  def self.rooms_with_smoking(smoking)
    self.where('smoking = ?', smoking)
  end

  def self.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date)
    self.joins(:visits).where('date >= ? and date <= ?', from_date, to_date).uniq
  end

  def self.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date)
    self.where.not(id: Room.occupied_rooms(from_date, to_date))
  end

  def self.find_rooms_with(occupancy_count, smoking, from_date, to_date)
    Room.vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date).joins(:layout).where('occupancy_count >= ?', occupancy_count).where('smoking = ?', smoking)
  end  

  def self.rooms_with_occupancy_and_smoking(occupancy_count, smoking)
    layouts = Layout.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count) //method self explanatory
    Room.rooms_with_smoking(smoking).joins(layouts) //method self explanatory
  end

  def self.blahblah(occupancy_count, smoking, from_date, to_date)
    layouts = Layout.layouts_with_occupancy_count_gt(occupancy_count)
    Room.rooms_with_smoking(smoking).vacant_rooms(from_date, to_date).joins(layouts)
  end

  def self.lowest_room_rate(hotel_id)
    self.where('hotel_id = ?', hotel_id).select(:rate).order(:rate).first
  end

  def self.highest_room_rate(hotel_id)
    self.where('hotel_id = ?', hotel_id).select(:rate).order(:rate).last
  end
end
```

Comment: Are your filenames correct, is the Layout class declared in app/models/layout.rb?

Comment: You should post your model codes - show us how you've created / structured them

Comment: I've added them to the original post.